# Yii 1.1.13 dies with error 500 after using addError

Tags: php, yii

I'm working on a tool which uses Yii version 1.1.13 and after addig new error messages with the `addError`method, despite it worked fine on the page I used it, it threw a strange, long error message on the *index* page with an *error 500*.

```
Missing argument 1 for CModel::getError(), called in /var/www/html/framework/base/CComponent.php on line 111 and defined (/var/www/html/framework/base/CModel.php:371)
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/protected/models/Testcases.php(132): Testcases->__get()
#1 /var/www/html/protected/views/site/index.php(189): Testcases->search()
#2 /var/www/html/framework/web/CBaseController.php(126): require()
#3 /var/www/html/framework/web/CBaseController.php(95): SiteController->renderInternal()
#4 /var/www/html/framework/web/CController.php(869): SiteController->renderFile()
#5 /var/www/html/framework/web/CController.php(782): SiteController->renderPartial()
#6 /var/www/html/protected/controllers/SiteController.php(295): SiteController->render()
#7 /var/www/html/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): SiteController->actionIndex()
#8 /var/www/html/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#9 /var/www/html/framework/web/CController.php(286): SiteController->runAction()
#10 /var/www/html/framework/web/CController.php(265): SiteController->runActionWithFilters()
#11 /var/www/html/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): SiteController->run()
#12 /var/www/html/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
#13 /var/www/html/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#14 /var/www/html/index.php(13): CWebApplication->run()
REQUEST_URI=/index.php
in /var/www/html/protected/models/Testcases.php (132)
in /var/www/html/protected/views/site/index.php (189)
in /var/www/html/protected/controllers/SiteController.php (295)
```

This bug appeared after generating test cases for my new error message. Then I reverted my modified file from the svn repository as the previous version worked fine, but I still can't get rid of this message.

I added the new errors like this:

```
if (FieldsQueue::model()->exists("fieldname = 'something'"))
                $model->addError('Error', "Something happened");
            else if (!isset($_POST['something'])) 
                $model->addError('test',"This is the new error);
            else { do something }
```

Thanks in advance for your helping answers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved, there was a row in the database which caused an error, I still don't know how, and which one was it (I just deleted some I added recently before the bug appeared). It is actually very strange because there wasn't anything about the DB in this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hii The `definition` of `addError` is

```
public void addError(string $attribute, string $error)
```

`$attribute` Should be your `model (db) attribute`

In your code

```
$model->addError('Error', "Something happened");
```

`Error` Should be your `model` `attribute`

Comment: Umm.. In this file I already had some addError rows (which were written by someone else), and when I search for the given attributes in the whole project (that are working properly) there is no match except in this controller. So I think these aren't defined anywhere else, but still working somehow, except that I wrote into it.